# Watershed a catalog RasterStack in place of RasterLayer in lidR?

Tags: raster, r, error, watershed, lidr

I want to use watershed with lidR package on a catalog. I paste this command:

```
rep <- "/home/lasfiles"
new_ctg <- catalog(rep)
lidR:::catalog_laxindex(new_ctg)
opt_output_files(new_ctg) <- paste0(rep, "/outputs/mnh/{ID}_cano")
opt_chunk_size(new_ctg) <- 500
opt_chunk_buffer(new_ctg) <- 30
opt_cores(new_ctg) <- 7L
algo <- pitfree(thresholds = c(0,10,20,30,40,50), subcircle = 0.2)
chm <- grid_canopy(new_ctg, 0.5, algo)
```

The result CHM is ok,

```
summary(chm)

        grid_canopy
 Min.       1305.953
 1st Qu.    1406.373
 Median     1468.121
 3rd Qu.    1539.043
 Max.       1716.370
 NA's        180.000
 Warning message:
 In .local(object, ...) :
     summary is an estimate based on a sample of 1e+05 cells (5% of 
     all cells)
```

but when I pass this command:

```
algo <- watershed(chm, th = 4)
```

> Error in assert_is_all_of(chm, "RasterLayer") : 
>     chm is not a RasterLayer it is RasterStack.

Why this error?

Comment: Seems like a bug. It should be a `RasterLayer`. Please make a reproducible example. Your code does not enable us to reproduce. This is regularly tested internally in the package and `grid_canopy` returns always a `RasterLayer`. You either made a mistake somewhere else or you found a limit case with a bug. We need more context.

Comment: Edit your question and if you can't demonstrate this on data we can use you could at least show the output of `summary(chm)` for context.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You chose to write the rasters into files with the option `opt_output_files`. By choosing this option, the output of `grid_canopy` is no longer a `RasterLayer` but a Virtual Raster Mosaic (see `gdalUtils::gdalbuildvrt`).

In `lidR` VRT are loaded back as `RasterStack` and not a `RasterLayer` as expected. This is why you encountered such error. This is an improvement that should be made.

You can extract only the first (and actually unique) layer as `RasterLayer`:

```
chm = chm[[1]]
```

---

That being said, `lidR` is made to process point-clouds and potentially wide point-clouds as far as possible but it is not made for processing wide rasters. Thus the `watershed` function has not been designed to efficiently process your rasters. I'm not even sure it can process a VRT. When created, it was more designed to work with small size CHM. But it should work anyway with a `RasterLayer`. Just be careful it will be all loaded in memory.

What you found may be considered as a bug. I opened [an issue](https://github.com/Jean-Romain/lidR/issues/222) to report an enhancement.